# How to AJAX Save Post nested list, with DIVs

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, nested-lists

I need help in saving `Sortable` nested list via `Ajax`. I looked up other SO answers, *but the difference/challenge is the `DIV` inside the `UL` and `LI` items*

Given that 1) its `sortable` list and 2) the list contains the `Div`, How can I:

1. save/POST AJAX this on server side?
2. and get/reconstruct the list back to the same HTML?

I tried $ () sortable serialize to array it was empty everytime

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div>
        <ul class="mcontainer">
            <li>
                <div>MenuItem</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>MenuItem.1</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>MenuItem.1.1</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>MenuItem.1.2</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>MenuItem.1.3</div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>MenuItem.1.3.1</div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <div>MenuItem.1.3.1.1</div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <div>MenuItem.1.3.1.2</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>MenuItem.1.3.1</div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>MenuItem.2</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>MenuItem.2.1</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>MenuItem.2.2</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>MenuItem.3</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>MenuItem.3.1</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>MenuItem.3.2</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>MenuItem.3.3</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The MenuItems should be input type elements. You cannot post a text only.

Comment: I read on SO that Jquery uses Parm, and so I can post anything back like a DOM fragment, are you saying this is not possible? please help me understand what options do I have, I dont want to make this a form simply - I thought JSON `serialize` gave me that capability to serialize $(#menu).(`serialize`)...

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible however if you really want to post the MenuItems, then you can create a hidden field that will take the value of the menu item then that's the one you can post.